# Creating a named .txt file and subsequently writing string to it in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been tasked to build a WPF App which uses a user input form to gather information, and then save the information as string in a text file, whose name is created as a result of user input. The UI and user input are working, but the string will not save to the text file. Whenever the code is debugged it throws a "file path not supported exception".

This is the code for my writing to the file:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\Users\\jhump\\Desktop\\TestingApp\\"+filename+"\\", data);
```

Where data is a string array containing the string to be saved, and filename is the concatted name for the file to be saved as.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This wouldn't even compile, you're missing double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape `\` characters by using an extra backslash like this `\\`. Also you can use [String Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), like `@"C:\Users\..."` instead if you don't want to use double backslashes.

```
string[] data = { "Some", "Thing", "Foo", "Bar" };
string filename = "foo.txt";

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\Users\\jhump\\Desktop\\TestingApp\\" + filename, data);
```

Comment: I keep getting the error : The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: can you update question with.. your filename and data you are passing?

Comment: I have fixed it now, I was making the file name as user input from a text box, but I missed off putting the .Text

Comment: as a result, the variable contained symbols which weren't allowed in file names, but its fixed now :)

Comment: glad i could help.. :)

Comment: sorry I'm new to stack overflow, I don't really know what i'm pressing :/ ill re select yours

Answer (score 0):

You have to concat the names of the directory or either escape the \ backslash:

...WriteAllLines(@"C:\yourpath\here\filename.txt",data)

best way for the user home folder is to use special folder paths:

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)

Comment: I have tried this, but I keep having the error : The given path's format is not supported.